# Find coefficient of $x^{n}$ in $\frac{1}{(1-x)^3(1+x)^2}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

I want to find a general expression for $x^{n}$ in $\frac{1}{(1-x)^3(1+x)^2}$.

I have tried to use partial fraction but that got complicated and I got stuck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Note: I would need a closed form expression

Comment: What did you get for the partial fraction?

Comment: I got stuck because there are five terms and I couldn't get to a result

Comment: One major doubt I have here is whether $|x|\lt 1$

Comment: Yes. This is a generating function

Answer (score 3):

By [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))
$$ \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{n\geq 0}(n+1)x^n \tag{1}$$
and by replacing $x$ with $x^2$
$$ \frac{1}{(1-x^2)^2}=\sum_{n\geq 0}(n+1)x^{2n} \tag{2}$$
then by multiplying both sides by $\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3+\ldots$ we have
$$ \frac{1}{(1-x)(1-x^2)^2} = \sum_{m\geq 0}x^m \sum_{\substack{0\leq n\leq m\\n\text{ even}}}\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)\tag{3} $$
so the coefficient of $x^m$ in the LHS of $(3)$ is $\frac{(m+2)(m+4)}{8}$ is $m$ is even and $\frac{(m+1)(m+3)}{8}$ if $m$ is odd.

Comment: That's the kind of answer I enjoy reading ...

Answer (score 2):

Lord Shark is right, do the partial fractions
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{(1+x)^2 (1-x)^3} = \frac{3/16}{1+x}+\frac{1/8}{(1+x)^2}+\frac{3/16}{1-x}+\frac{1/4}{(1-x)^2}+\frac{1/4}{(1-x)^3}. \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Now each of these terms can be expanded geometrically
\begin{eqnarray*}\frac{1}{(1+x)^2 (1-x)^3} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{3}{16}(-1)^n+\frac{1}{8}(-1)^n (n+1) +\frac{3}{16}+\frac{1}{4}(n+1)+\frac{1}{8}(n+1)(n+2) \right)x^n. \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbf{Hint:} $

$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^3(1+x)^2}$$
$$=\frac{1}{(1-x^2)^2(1-x)}$$
$$= \left(\sum_{r=0} \binom{r+1}{r}.x^{2r}\right).\left(\sum_{r=0} x^{r}\right)$$
Can you take it from here

Comment: I tried that, but how can I get a closed expression of the coefficient of $x^{n}$ this way?

Comment: Can You please post what you have tried so that I get a better idea of where you got stuck

Comment: I have tried partial fractions: $A/(x + 1) + B/(x + 1)^2 + C/(x-1) +  D/(x - 1)^2 + E/(x - 1)^3$

Comment: I don't see how your way can lead to a closed form as it is a multiplication of generating functions

Comment: All you can get is a sum.

Answer (score 0):

More generally,
consider
$\dfrac{1}{(1-x)^a(1+x)^b}$.

From the generalized binomial theorem
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Generalizations),

$(1-x)^{-s}
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{s+k-1}{k}x^k
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{s+k-1}{s-1}x^k
$.

Therefore
$(1-x)^{-a}
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{a+k-1}{a-1}x^k
$
and
$(1+x)^{-b}
=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \binom{b+j-1}{b-1}(-1)^jx^k
$.

Using the standard
Cauchy product,

$(1-x)^{-a}(1+x)^{-b}
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n\sum_{m=0}^n \binom{a+m-1}{a-1}\binom{b+n-m-1}{b-1}(-1)^{n-m}
$,
so the coefficient of $x^n$ is
$\sum_{m=0}^n \binom{a+m-1}{a-1}\binom{b+n-m-1}{b-1}(-1)^{n-m}
$.

As to whether this can be simplified,
I don't know.

Maybe something Vandermondish.